# How to implement advanced UI designs in Android

Tags: android, user-interface

I've seen a lot of articles on how to do UI designs with Linear and Relative Layouts, but haven't seen anything that specifically shows you how to create UI like these:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojSHM.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNXaO.jpg

Are these just a collection of images (ie a photoshop design sliced up)?  If so, are there any example apps/articles/tutorials that show how to take a photoshop design, slice it appropriately, and how to properly code this in eclipse for multiple android devices?

I'm not looking for articles that show me how to use Linear layouts as I've seen a dozen of those.  I'm looking for something that takes a design and implements it.  Something more advanced like the images above.

Thanks!

Take care,
Shannon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me shared my view for these 2 designs:

1. Facebook dashboard window:

   - The blue top bar and bottom notification background image are created using `9-patch` tool.
   - The middle part icons "News Feed","Profile" are the gridview with 3 column and possible horizontal spacing/vertical spacing.
   - The 2nd bottom part may be created using Image Gallery View.
2. 2nd has contains mastery of RelativeLayout, it has prepared using Sectioned ListView in middle part , and everything others are implemented using RelativeLayout with buttons.

FYI, mostly background images/icons are prepared using 9-patch tool. Using 9-patch image we can create a scalable graphics.

Comment: Thanks!  That gives me a great insight into how something like that is implemented.  Appreciate it.

Comment: @ShannonCole Cheers :) Keep thinking about the few existing application's UI and then you will get idea for your app as well.

Answer (score 0):

None of those appear to use the process you describe.

The menu bars are done with a plastic effect background.

The icons are just that

Drop shadows are a feature of android's views.  So that doesn't require custom graphics.

What you are probably missing here is that the icons etc. will use transparent PNG's to make stuff blend.